# Is it possible to store custom graphics (such as ROC-Curve) in Sagemaker Model Registry?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I try to store some graphics with my Pipeline/Model in Sagemaker. So far, I've only been able to store Metrics in a JSON/PropertyFile, but I would like to store some visualizations as well.

Is this possible with Sagemaker (Studio) Model Registry?

In the general description it seems so: https://aws.amazon.com/de/sagemaker/mlops/?sagemaker-data-wrangler-whats-new.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&sagemaker-data-wrangler-whats-new.sort-order=desc

I learned about custom metadata, but this doesn't seem to include images, does it?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateModelPackage.html#sagemaker-CreateModelPackage-request-CustomerMetadataProperties

For AutoML storing graphics seems to be possible: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/autopilot-model-insights.html